# Ethics of Spinoza - eatenus

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-explanation, ethica

Spinoza, Ethics, De Deo, Propositio 15, Scholium:

> Exempli gratia  aquam quatenus aqua est, dividi concipimus ejusque partes ab invicem separari; at non quatenus substantia **est** corporea; **eatenus** enim neque separatur neque dividitur.

Boyle translation:

> E.g., we can conceive water, in so far as it is water, to be divided and its parts separated one from the other: but not in so far as *it is a corporeal substance*, for **then** it is neither separated nor divided

Elwes translation:

> For instance, water, in so far as it is water, we conceive to be divided, and its parts to be separated one from the other; but not in so far as *it is extended substance*; **from this point of view** it is neither separated nor divisible

I have two questions.

1- Translations are so as if the text is:

> at non quatenus **est** substantia corporea

Why?

2- If **eatenus** means **so far**, why are translation otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - I don't think Latin makes much of a distinction between *substantia est corporea* and *est substantia corporea*. In either case, I think you'll need to rely on context to determine which English translation to use.

2 - *Eatenus* is the correlative to *quatenus*. Both translations use "insofar as" to translate *quatenus*. It seems to me that there is nothing wrong with Boyle using "then" as a correlative for "insofar as", although better correlatives could be found (and I think the one you found is better). Elwes' choice of all but abandoning the correlative in favor of re-phrasing is an interesting one, which really drives home the point. It's not the choice I would have made, but I don't think it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

1- I find another example of coming **est** among the predicate and its adjective in the Spinoza's text:

Spinoza in *Propositio XVII, Scholium* denies that God has by nature some perfections like intellect and will. He says that many person disagree with him, because:

> Nihil enim perfectius cognoscere sese  aiunt quod Deo tribuere possunt quam id quod in nobis *summa* **est** *perfectio*

Which means:

> For they say they know nothing more perfect, which they can attribute to God, than that which **is** *the highest perfection* in us

2-
**Eatenus** can mean **to such a degree**. Thus meaning of sentence may be so:

> for water **to such a degree** (*in that status which water is still an extended substance and not a tangible object*) is neither separated nor divisible